# How can i echo a string with escape sequences in Nim?

Tags: nim-lang

If I echo a string like this:

```
let s = "Hello\nworld"
echo s
```

I get:

```
Hello
world
```

I would like to output:
`Hello\nworld`

I know I can use raw string literals if I'm defining the string, but how do i do it if the string comes from, for example, a file?

I guess I'm looking for something similar to pythons `repr()` function.

**edit**: There is a repr function for Nim. However, the output is not what i'm looking for:

```
let hello = "hello\nworld"
echo repr(hello)

---- Output ----
0x7fc69120b058"hello\10"
"world"
```

Comment: Have you tried "Hello\\nworld"?

Comment: As i noted in the question, assume I get the string from a file. The content is not known ahead of time. But to answer your question, yes i have tried it, and it works. So does `let s = r"Hello\nworld"`. But that doesn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use escape function from strutils package.

```
import strutils

let s = "Hello\nWorld"
echo s.escape()
```

This will print:

```
Hello\x0AWorld
```

Current strutils escape function implementation escapes newline into hex value. You can use the following code to do it the way python does.

```
func escape(s: string): string =
  for c in items(s):
    case c
    of '\0'..'\31', '\34', '\39', '\92', '\127'..'\255':
      result.addEscapedChar(c)
    else: add(result, c)

let s = "Hello\nWorld"
echo s.escape()
```

Output:

```
Hello\nWorld
```

Here is documentation links for [escape](https://nim-lang.org/docs/strutils.html#escape%2Cstring%2Cstring%2Cstring) and [addEscapeChar](https://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#addEscapedChar,string,char) functions

Answer (score 0):

How about a using:

```
let s = r"Hello\nWorld"                                                                                                                  
echo s
```

will output:

```
Hello\nWorld
```

Comment: Please read the question, and the comment I made to the question :) "I know I can use raw string literals if I'm defining the string, but how do i do it if the string comes from, for example, a file?". What you just showed me is called a raw string literal.